# How to use Globalize.js to configure culture for client side validation in ASP.NET Core MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, globalize, jquery-globalize

I having very hard time to configure client side validation in my app. I would like to it be able to accept localized `pt-BR` inputs.

I tried configure the app using at startup:

```
var locale = "pt-BR";
RequestLocalizationOptions localizationOptions = new RequestLocalizationOptions {
    SupportedCultures   = new List<CultureInfo> { new CultureInfo(locale) },
    SupportedUICultures = new List<CultureInfo> { new CultureInfo(locale) },
    DefaultRequestCulture = new RequestCulture(locale)
};
```

It works for rendering currency, date time and numbers in server side, but the client validation still expecting `en-US` input.

The client side is using `jquery.validate` and `jquery.validate.unobtrusive`
Then I was advised to use Globalize.js.

I installed globalize by npm `npm instal globalize@1.0.0`
And it added the globalize package and the `cldr.js` packages. And downloaded the `jquery.validate.globalize.js` to the project

I added reference to the js files in the HTML

```
<!-- cldr scripts (needed for globalize) -->
<script src="~/lib/cldrjs/dist/cldr.js"></script>
<script src="~/lib/cldrjs/dist/cldr/event.js"></script>
<script src="~/lib/cldrjs/dist/cldr/supplemental.js"></script>
<script src="~/lib/cldrjs/dist/cldr/unresolved.js"></script>

<!-- globalize scripts -->
<script src="~/lib/globalize/dist/globalize.js"></script>
<script src="~/lib/globalize/dist/globalize/number.js"></script>
<script src="~/lib/globalize/dist/globalize/date.js"></script>

<!-- Validation -->
<script src="~/lib/jquery.validate.globalize.js"></script>
```

but unfortunately I am getting this error when i try to se the location `Globalize.locale("pt-BR")`

> E_MISSING_CLDR: Missing required CLDR content `supplemental/likelySubtags`.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to load CLDR data using `Globalize.load`. Please see https://github.com/globalizejs/globalize/blob/master/doc/cldr.md